# Не доконца отрабатывает очередь

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php8

Разрабатываю сервис и тестирую через postman.

Есть очередь.

Которая обрабатывает данные, как выглядит к примеру.

```
 Controller call JobCalc.

JobCalc{
 while($condition){
  body code;
  }
 call function statistics($parameter);
 call new JOB
 }
```

Когда обрабатывает данные с 1000 строк. Все отрабатывает хорошо, передавая параметры в следующий JOB, и все заканчивается успехом.

Когда данные приходят в 15000 строк. В цикле все отрабатывается, но дольше джоб и функция не вызывается.

В логах и в базе в таблице failed_jobs ничего нету.

В php.ini увеличил память до 1024 мб,так же время выполнения скрипта,без результатно.
Уже не знаю куда смотреть.

Вставлял echo после вызова job в controller,что бы посмотреть идет ли дальше код после первого вызова job, все отрабатывает.

Код не кидаю,бо там около 1500 строк,структуру приблизительно описал.

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в памяти.
Так как логику писал не я, а до меня, в код лезть было сложно.

While жрет память не очищает,решение было использовать

```
LazyCollection::make(function (){
    $fh = fopen($absolutePath, 'r');
    while ($record_data = fgetcsv($fh)) {
            yield $record_data;
        }
   })->chunk(500)->each(function ($items){
      foreach ($items as $item){  
         //logic
     }
   }
```

Это сократило обьем используемой памяти раза в 3-4. Все начало работать как и задумывалось.